# Unable to call function in modal -closed-

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm quite new with web development. I have a register modal in register.php that is able to return a check function from the submit button, to submit an API call.

[image]

But when I run this it from my index page, the function does not seem to be called.

[image]

header.php

```
<?php 
   include ('includes/login.php');
   include ('includes/register.php');
?>
```

register.php

```
<button class="regsubmit" type="submit" style="float:left;" id="submitButton" onclick="return chk()">Submit</button>
            <button class="regcancel" type="button" id="cancelButton"
                onclick="window.location='#';return false;">Cancel</button>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
function chk() {
    var fname=document.getElementById('fname').value;
    var lname=document.getElementById('lname').value;
    var emailAddress =  document.getElementById('emailAddress').value;
    var bdayMonth = document.getElementById('bdayMonth').value;
    var bdayDay = document.getElementById('bdayDay').value;
    var bdayYear = document.getElementById('bdayYear').value;
    var regPassword = document.getElementById('regPassword').value;
    var confirmPassword = document.getElementById('confirmPassword').value;
    var gender = document.getElementById('gender').value;
    var dataString='fname='+ fname+'&lname='+lname+'&emailAddress='+emailAddress+'&bdayMonth='+bdayMonth+'&bdayDay='+bdayDay+'&bdayYear='+bdayYear+'&confirmPassword='+confirmPassword+'&regPassword='+regPassword+'&gender='+gender;

    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url: "processRegister.php",
        data:dataString,
        cache:false,
        success: function(data){
        if (/^\s*SUCCESS\s*$/.test(data)) {
        window.location = '<?php echo $base_url; ?>index.php?success=true';
           }
        else{
             alert(data);
          }
        }
    });
        return false;
}
</script>
```

*edit: i ran an alert() at the start of the function and tried to run in on my index again, the alert was able to show but not the function.*

Comment: Are you missing with other parts of the form elements? Check in the console if there are any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers but was finally able to solve it after ensuring everything was loaded as mentioned above. After checking with alert that the function was running, i concluded that it was my ajax error. Seems like it couldn't access my processRegister.php which was located inside my includes folder, had to link it properly and it's all good. Another way was to move my processRegister.php outside of the folder.

Answer (score 0):

I would check to make sure the page is loaded be is loaded before you run the function.

```
window.onload = function() {
  //code that runs after document is loaded.
}
```